# Can a “collaborator” delete code “inside” a repository?

Tags: git, github

Basically,

We may be firing a contractor, assigned as a collaborator to our GitHub.

As a collaborator - Can they:

1. delete all the code in the repositories and it’s branches?
2. Can collaborator “merge” all branches - to purposely cause “conflict” making code unusable/unreadable?

If any of these questions are possible.. how do we protect the repository and its branches?

I am aware of the branch protections, I do not see anywhere in there *a tick box* alluding to (check here for collaborator to not delete anything)

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Just remove them as a collaborator? And anyone with a copy of the repository has its full history. It doesn't sound like you're familiar with how to "remove" files in git. You have to force push to permanently remove history, otherwise all removals and additions are still in git history. You can add force push protection to branches in Github. It doesn't matter since it's easy to revert to older commits from anyone else's machine.

Comment: Yes, they can. A collaborator can basically force push to all non-protected branches to overwrite history.

Comment: It will at least be very hard for them to totally ruin everything. Since git is a distributed versioning tool it means that even if he remove every remote branch the ones actually working on said branches will have it locally :)

Comment: ^ building off @Kim's answer: https://github.blog/2019-05-14-git-ransom-campaign-incident-report/

What you describe has already been tried as a ransomware attack that netted something like $7 **total**. Most affected teams just had someone push a pre-ransomware version, and the SREs at the three providers handled the rest with arcane sysadmin magic (also known as "a backup").